# Get the event onchange after JavaScript change select's value

Tags: ajax, select, onchange

I have a form in which the user can save. In this form I have a dynamic SELECT, when user chooses an option with the event ONCHANGE I get the result of another SELECT. The problem is that when user loads his saved form I need to select with JavaScript his selected option(saved before) but I can't to get the onchange event to load the other select.

Answer (score 0):

This is using jquery. On the dom ready, you select the value for your first select box, then run the function to populate the second select. Next, you're selecting the right value for that second box. On the change, you re run the function to populate your second select

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#firstselect").val(the value you wanted for the first select);
     function that populates values of your second select box();

    $("#id of your second select").val(the value you wanted for the second select);

    $('firstselect').change(run your function that populates your second select)

});
```